# How to change number format in locale for GnuCash?

Tags: 12.10, locale

When I start GnuCash it displays negative numbers in "€ 100,0-" format, while I want it like "€ -300.0"
How can I change it?

Locale settings:

```
~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing minus sign is a consequence of the Dutch local (`nl_NL`).

You're not supposed to change that from GnuCash ([so they say](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Locale_Settings)), but you might try to change the `LC_MONETARY` category in your system.

It seems to me that you can try something like ([read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)):

```
LC_MONETARY=ll_LL.UTF-8
export LC_MONETARY
```

substituting `ll_LL.UTF-8` with an appropriate locale name. From [the manpage for `setlocale`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/setlocale.3.html):

> A     locale     name      is      typically      of      the      form
>          language[_territory][.codeset][@modifier], where language is an ISO 639
>          language code, territory is an ISO 3166 country code, and codeset is  a
>          character  set  or encoding identifier like ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8.  For a
>          list of all supported locales, try "locale -a", cf. locale(1).